# Custom Progress bar with multiple colors, in Android

Tags: android

Does anyone have a good resource on creating custom progress bar graphics in Android. I currently have a progress bar that displays data specific to the results of each test that is taken. 
I need a bar that will display the results of each specific test, but also in a diffrent color display the results of the best score in the database. (If your current score is higher the diffrence should be green, if lower the diffrence should be red).

I am having a though time finding documentation on the progress bar class in Android, and everything I find doesnt have info about displaying data from two diffrent sources.

Comment: [Custom Progress Bar In Android](http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.com/2013/05/custom-progress-bar-in-android.html)

Comment: Try this, it's a nice tutorial

Answer (score 0):

This is more what I was looking for but thanks for the help 
http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-create-custom-progress-bar-and.html